# Django - combining querysets from different models and serializing them

Tags: django, django-models

I am a newbie trying to build an e-commerce website for fun. Firstly, I take the query parameters from the url, then find the fitting products and then try to find the corresponding images. However I cannot find a way to:

1. combine a queryset of products and a queryset of images (connected with each other by a foreign key)
2. serialize them into a JSON, to show on the frontend

I am using postgresql.

*Sample url*
`http://localhost:3000/products/?slider=%5B500%2C8000%5D&service=1&stars=%5B3%2C4%2C5%5D`

*models.py*

```
class Hotel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price_per_person = models.FloatField()
    service = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    stars = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    description = models.TextField()

class Image(models.Model):
    hotel = models.ForeignKey(Hotel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', null=True)
```

*views.py*

```
@api_view(["GET"])
def getProductsView(req):

    productsSet = Hotel.objects.all()

    for key, value in req.GET.items():
        value = json.loads(value)
        if key == "stars":
            orStatement = Q(stars=value[0])
            for star in value[1:]:
                orStatement = orStatement | Q(stars=star)

            productsSet = productsSet.filter(orStatement)

        elif key == "slider":
            productsSet = productsSet.filter(price_per_person__range=(value[0], value[1]))
        else:
            productsSet = productsSet.filter(**{key: value})

    productsSet = productsSet[:25]

    imageSet = Image.objects.filter(
        hotel_id__in=[i for i in productsSet.values_list("id", flat="True")]
    )

    # Tried 
    # productsSet.union(imageSet)
    # but the result didn't change
        
    serializer = HotelSerializer(
        productsSet, context={"request": req}, many=True
    )

    return Response(serializer.data)
```

I tried calling django's union, but to no avail and I want to find a more effective solution than just turning each element of the productsSet into a JSON and adding an images array to it

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add your serializer class as well to provide a better answer.
You can either add 'depth=1' in your serializer Meta class, or add extra field that provides the image url only as well.